# Corda - Gradle Error With Quasar When Upgrading to Corda 4.3

Tags: gradle, corda, quasar

I've updated my `build.gradle` file to Corda 4.3, however applying this plugin...

```
apply plugin: 'net.corda.plugins.quasar-utils'
```

...causes the following error when trying to refresh gradle...

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'template'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'net.corda.plugins.quasar-utils']
   > Could not create an instance of type net.corda.plugins.QuasarExtension_Decorated.
      > No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultPropertyState.convention() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [co.paralleluniverse]
```

Any ideas what is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with gradle-5.4.1?

Source : https://www.corda.net/blog/corda-version-upgrade-guide/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem executing Corda 4.4 release. Basically you have to update your gradle version to recognize some dependencies in gradle.

First of all, execute the comand: `gradle -version`

[image: gradle -version to check your gradle version]

After that, you have to update your gradle version according to the gradle version supported by your current Corda version. In my case, It is supported by gradle version 5.4.1. So, to execute an upgrade, try this: `./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 5.4.1`

[image: upgrading the gradle version]

Next, check again your gradle version using ./gradlew --version (in the CorDapp directory)
[image: showing the new gradle version]

Finally, you can execute your task. So, in my case I would like to execute a test with heap dump allocating more memory and check an OOM. I execute the follow command:

```
./gradlew test -Dlog4j.configurationFile=../config/test/log4j2.xml -Dcapsule.jvm.args=["-Xmx10G","-Xms512m","-XX:+UseG1GC","-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"]
```

[image: The tests are being executed with my configuration]

That is it!